# Item não é apagado dinamicamente usando foreach

Tags: php, formulário

Estou num pequeno impasse resolvível mas não de minha cabeça no momento. Tenho uma lista de itens no qual um botão de exclusão para cada item. Estes itens são removidos passando como parâmetro o `UUID`. Se fixar um valor para o `UUID` fora do `foreach`, ele é apagado normalmente, porém ao criar os itens dinamicamente, não consigo apagar o item selecionado.

***Form hardcore:*** (funciona)

```
<form id='form_delete_action' method='POST' action=''>
   <tr>
      <input type='hidden' name='function' value='delete_action'>
      <input type='hidden' name='uuid' value='182nagojvgaf'>
      <button name="delete_action" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">excluir</button>
   </tr>
</form>
```

***Form dinâmico:*** (não funciona)

```
foreach($json['actions'] as $item) {
echo "
<form role='form' id='form_delete_action' method='POST' action=''>
   <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='vehicle' value='car'></td>
      <input type='hidden' name='function' value='delete_action'>
      <input type='hidden' name='uuid' value='".$item['uuid']."'>
      <td>".$item['uuid']."</td>
      <td>".$item['created_at']."</td>
      <td>".$item['description']."</td>
      <td>".$item['category']."</td>
      <td>".$item['request_at']."</td>
      <td>".$item['value']."</td>
      <td>
         <button name='delete_action' type='submit' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>excluir</button>
      </td>
   </tr>
</form>
";
}
```

Talvez não seja muito relativo, porém abaixo segue o jQuery no qual uso para exclusão:

```
jQuery('#form_delete_action').submit(function(){
    var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "core/functions.php",
        data: dados,
        success: function( data )
        {
            //alert($("#description").val() + " - "+ $("#category").val() + " - "+ $("#type").val() + " - "+ $("#value").val());
            location.reload();
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Dentro do `core/functions.php` está as chamadas da API para adicionar, editar e excluir.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: E o deletar cada? ou tem algum javascript aí?

Comment: @Miguel E aquele 1%? talvez sim, talvez não. Vou fazer um teste!

Comment: você tem um `foreach` de formulários, não é um boa prática. Mas acontece que além de usar a mesma `name` em todas as inputs `uuid`, você também utiliza a mesma `<form role='form' id='form_delete_action' method='POST' action=''>` em todos os formulários

Comment: @LeonardoRodrigues tudo bem, já tirei o form, mas continua o impasse.

Comment: Bom, se a sugestão do @Miguel não funcionou, tenta além de alterar as `names` da inputs, atribuir `names` diferentes para os `forms`. Minha sugestão seria criar uma `Key` para cada item, onde você utilizaria em `name`, tanto nos formulários quanto nas inputs

Comment: Como vc faz para remover o item é direto com php ou tem algum javascript?

Comment: @rray eu uso jquery para excluir sem sair da página. ^^

Comment: Se você usa `jQuery`, ao submeter um formulário ele deve apresentar identificações diferentes. Sendo assim todos os formulários devem possui `name`, e de preferência uma `id` própria.

Comment: Se vc pega o id do botão ou do input com o jquery, veja que não será retornado um valor e sim uma coleção, na hora de excluir vc precisa indicar quem acionou o evento (do click imagino eu)

Comment: @rray note que usando o uuid hardcore exclui normalmente, considerando usar o mesmo nome do formulário.

Comment: Eu acho que está faltando código na pergunta ... posta o jquery q vc usa.

Comment: Você possui um gatilho `type='submit'` dentro do seu código, sendo assim cada formulário são submetidos ao clicar nele, e você pode pegar este evento, tendo o formulário exato em questão, através da função `.submit()`: https://api.jquery.com/submit/. De qualquer forma, você deveria postar a função `jQuery` que está utilizando

Comment: @LeonardoRodrigues adicionei o jquery, porém não acho que seja tão relativo assim.

Comment: faz um teste por favor, depois da função `serialize();`, tente `console.log(dados );` e poste na pergunta também.

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio o log não funciona, porque quando uso o submit, a pagina está sendo atualizada, desta forma, não da pra ver nada no log. q cossa extranha

Comment: Adicione `event.preventDefault();` dentro da função jquery para prevenir que ela seja atualizada, e tenta obter o log, ao verificar o log, verifique se os campos `uuid` estão corretos com os formulários em questão

Answer (score 1):

Não é uma boa prática ter vários formulários numa página só.

Não sei se posso dizer se está errado a forma **dinâmica** que você implementou, mas **eu** não utilizaria essa abordagem.

Eu faria assim:

```
echo "<form role='form' id='form_delete_action' method='POST' action=''>";
foreach($json['actions'] as $item) {
   echo "
   <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='vehicle' value='car'></td>
      <input type='hidden' name='function' value='delete_action'>
      <input type='hidden' name='uuid' class="idExcluir" value='".$item['uuid']."'>
      <td>".$item['uuid']."</td>
      <td>".$item['created_at']."</td>
      <td>".$item['description']."</td>
      <td>".$item['category']."</td>
      <td>".$item['request_at']."</td>
      <td>".$item['value']."</td>
      <td>
         <button name='delete_action' type='submit' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs btnExcluir'>excluir</button>
      </td>
   </tr>";
} //fim do foreach
ECHO "</form>";
```

Perceba que eu adicionei uma `class btnExcluir` no botão de Excluir. E também coloquei uma `class idExcluir` no `input hidden` que eu assumi ser um identificador único do elemento que você quer excluir.

Agora basta tratar o clique dentro do formulário, especificamente no botão de exclusão:

```
$("#form_delete_action").on("click", ".btnExcluir", function() {
   var idElementoExcluir = $(this).closest(".idExcluir").val();

   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "core/functions.php",
        data: {idElementoExcluir: idElementoExcluir},
        success: function( data )
        {
            location.reload();
        }
    });

});
```

É claro que você vai precisar adaptar sua função php para receber o ID do elemento à excluir por parâmetro. Não sou muito bom em php, coloquei a ideia geral aqui do que eu faria pra poder resolver seu problema.

Ainda não entendi porquê do formulário estar com a action vazia. Se você utilizar a abordagem que eu sugeri, nem precisa de formulário. Somente da tabela.